# Subscribing to c# Events in F# With Partial Applications

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I have this working after a few hours of bashing my head.  Now I'm trying to understand why.

This is an event definition from a c# lib:

```
internal readonly AsyncEvent<Func<SocketMessage, Task>> _messageReceivedEvent = new AsyncEvent<Func<SocketMessage, Task>>();
```

The only way it works is by passing in a (fun -> ) directly:

```
        helper.client.add_MessageReceived
            (fun msg ->
                processMsg msg)
```

It cannot be parameterized:

```
        let x = 
            (fun msg ->
                processMsg msg)
        
        helper.client.add_MessageReceived x
```

I initially tried to just pass the processMsg function.  It looked like the right signature:

```
        helper.client.add_MessageReceived processMsg
```

Comment: What is the exact signature of `add_MessageReceived`?

Comment: F# intellisense says ```BaseSocketClient.add_MessageReceived(value: System.Func<SocketMessage, Task>) : unit```

Comment: And my function is ```val processMsg : (SocketMessage -> Task)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `System.Func` is a [delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/delegates).

When you pass a lambda function to `add_MessageReceived`, the lambda is implicitly converted to a `System.Func`.

But in other cases, you need to explicitly do the converting:

```
let x = System.Func<_, _> (fun msg -> processMsg msg)
helper.client.add_MessageReceived x
```

Comment: Ok, I was thinking that partial applications were delegates.  This also works ```helper.client.add_MessageReceived (System.Func<SocketMessage, Task> (processMsg))```

Comment: I really like the functional paradigm over OO, but I keep banging my head into something every couple of days that really slows me down.

Comment: Don’t worry. It’s normal. That also happened to me and many of my friends when we started learning FP/F#.

Comment: Well, you have been very helpful and I'm grateful.  That implicit conversion to System.Func is really inconsistent and caused all the confusion.  Like in a language where "Email of string" requires you to acknowledge a constructor ```let x = Email "string"```, having ```Func<> (fun -> )``` be implicit based context is bad.

Comment: We use delegates in F# just because sometimes we need to work with C# code or other .NET libraries. As you see many discouraged features like null, exception... are still available in F# code. Pure FP code is beautiful IMHO.

Comment: Agreed, 100%.  It's the implicit part that bothers me, where ```let x = (fun -> )``` creates one type and ```csharp.add (fun -> )``` creates a diff type.  I figured out how to make it work way before I figured out why because of the implicit wrapper that was generated.

Comment: Actually the implicit conversion only happens when we use OO code: `add_MessageReceived` is a method of an object. If it was a function, the conversion must be explicitly.